# How to build archlinux pkgbuild inside docker with gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, archlinux, gitlab-ci

I need to use gitlab-ci with docker in order to automatically build and test archlinux packages on every commit.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: pritunl/archlinux

before_script:
  - pacman -Su pkgbuild-introspection --noconfirm

stages:
  - build

makepkg:
  script:
    - makepkg --clean --rmdeps --syncdeps --noarchive --noconfirm --noprogressbar --asdeps
  stage: build
```

All is well, but when CI call makepkg command I get this error:

```
==> ERROR: Running makepkg as root is not allowed as it can cause permanent, catastrophic damage to your system.

==> ERROR: An unknown error has occurred. Exiting...
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to run `makepkg` as root. If you run as root, `makepkg` can put files anywhere on your system rather than just in `$pkgdir` where that package is made from.  This is stopped by using [`fakeroot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System#fakeroot), which is disabled when run as `root`.

> A fake root is simply a subdirectory within the build directory that
>   functions and behaves as the system's root directory. In conjunction
>   with the fakeroot program, makepkg creates a fake root directory, and
>   installs the compiled binaries and associated files into it, with root
>   as owner.

I suggest you to extend the `pritunl/archlinux` image and add a simple user, just for `makepkg` operations.

Comment: Or without having to create a new image, create a new user from your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and use it for the `makepkg` command.

Comment: But makepkg need increase of privelagions when running as another user then root. How I can solve it?

Comment: something like that, is hacky trick, but its gain a root permission to user `echo 'your_user ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers`, but be carefully.

Comment: @Зелёный , thank you. Solved with `your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @CryptoManiac glad to hear, happy coding!